# Php scripts displays different date and time from my laptop date and time i want scripts to display my date and time

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

This is my config file on date and time.

Please, where can I also edit to get the date and time from my PC?

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
```

so i have this script that prints a report but the date and time doesnt match my pc date and time. code below

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="printableArea" style="margin-left:2px;">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            {company_info}
                            <h3> {company_name} </h3>
                            <h4 >{address} </h4>
                            {/company_info}
                            <h4> <?php echo display('print_date') ?>: <?php echo date("d/m/Y h:i:s"); ?> </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><?php echo display('sales_date') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo display('invoice_no') ?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo display('customer_name')?></th>
                                        <th><?php echo display('total_amount')?></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way to get the local date/time

```php
$dateTime = new DateTime("NOW", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

echo $dateTime->format("d/m/yyyy H:i:s");
```

Also, you can use the [**localtime**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php) from PHP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @Ahmad i would try it out buh where should i put this code to get the datetime on all the scripts.

Comment: @Simon I don't see your codebase so can not say where, but mainly check if you have a shared a file or something you always include it or it is always shown and add this code snippet there.
Hope this gives an idea as it is hard to tell :)

Comment: ohk @Ahmad buh i would like to get the date and time on all my scipts so what can i do sir